# How to customize novel class?

Tags: luatex

I have to to customize a file written with Novel class. I'd need to add a table of contents and modify \SetRectoHeadText{} in order to have the current chapter name. How could I do that?

This is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{novel} % See list of class options; usually none needed.
%%% METADATA (FILE DATA):
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\SetTitle{My title} % Required for PDF/X.
\SetSubtitle{My subtitle} % Default: empty.
\SetAuthor{My name} % Default: empty.
\SetApplication{LuaLaTeX with novel and microtype}
\SetProducer{LuaLaTeX with novel-pdfx and hyperref}
\SetPDFX[CGATSTR001]{X-1a:2001}
%%% DIMENSIONS:
\SetTrimSize{5.5in}{8.5in} % Sets width, height of your book.
% Default Media Size equals Trim Size.
% Rarely-used over-ride, except for cover artwork:
% \SetMediaSize[alignment]{width}{height}
% Default margins vary with Trim Size. Defaults for {5.5in}{8.5in}:
\SetMargins{0.80in}{0.80in}{0.80in}{0.80in}
%%% GENERAL FONTS:
% Percent at end of line is necessary, when writing font settings multi-line:
\SetParentFont[%
SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},% Effective when small caps requested locally.
Kerning=On, %
Ligatures=TeX, %
]{Libertinus Serif}
% Main text font automatically adds Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common.
% Default main font size is based on other layout settings.
% Varies from 11pt to 12pt. With all default layouts, value is 11.4pt.
% You may manually choose a different main font size:
% \SetFontSize{length}
% Default lines per page (main textblock) is calculated from other layout settings.
% When using all defaults, the calculated value is 35.
% If used, \SetLinesPerPage manually chooses the value:
% \SetLinesPerPage{integer}
\SetDecoFont{NovelDeco.otf}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math} % unicode-math
%%% HEADERS/FOOTERS:
\SetHeadFootStyle{1} % This style has headers only.
\SetHeadJump{2}
\SetFootJump{2}
\SetLooseHead{50}
\SetEmblems{}{} % Default blanks.
\SetHeadFont[\parentfontfeatures,Letters=SmallCaps,Scale=0.92]{\parentfontname}
\SetPageNumberStyle{\thepage}
\SetVersoHeadText{\theTitle}
\SetRectoHeadText{\theSubtitle}
%%% CHAPTERS:
\SetChapterStartStyle{footer} % Equivalent to empty, when style has no footer.
\SetChapterStartHeight{7}
\SetChapterFont[Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.6]{\parentfontname}
\SetSubchFont[Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.2]{\parentfontname}
\SetScenebreakIndent{false}
%%% CUSTOM FONTS:
% \NewFontFamily[]{} % Optional command.
% \NewFontFace[]{} % Optional command.
% \CreateFontFeature{}{} % Optional command.
%%% OTHER:
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english} % polyglossia
\microtypesetup{config=novel-microtype,stretch=20,shrink=20,final} % microtype
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT:
\begin{document}
\frontmatter % Sets page number to i.
\mainmatter % Sets page number to 1 for following material.\mainmatter % Required
% Chapters go here. SAMPLE Chapter structure:
\clearpage % or \cleartorecto
\begin{ChapterStart}
\vspace*{2\nbs} % Space above chapter title. \nbs = normal baseline skip.
\ChapterTitle{A title} % Perhaps also ChapterSubtitle, ChapterDeco.
\end{ChapterStart}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have any suggestion which would allows me to make this template an ordinary book template (same size with fancy style), I'll take it.

Comment: My impression is that the class has been written with the precise intent that no customization other than those provided are possible. Of course they can be done, but the code is *very* intricated.

Comment: That's the reason why I suggested that any proposition to set a similar template would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of the `novel` document class. The above comment by @egreg, about not intending further customization (without difficulty) is exactly correct. The reason is that `novel` is intended to produce PDF that meets certain printing industry standards. If the user adds code that produces a valid, but non-standard PDF, it cannot be detected by `novel`. A program such as Adobe Acrobat Pro would detect it (then the printer would detect it).

I requested CTAN to retire `novel`, based on possible issues with recent TeXlive binaries. But it still works for me (TeXlive 2022, Linux). EDIT: No need to retire `novel`. The issues were transient, fixed in the binaries some time ago.